# Any power saving programs for a Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, apt, power-management

My laptop is getting pretty old, therefore the old battery in it doesn't last as long as it used to. I was wondering if there were any programs that I could install to save battery power. For example: `tlp`.

Comment: Replace your laptop battery?

Comment: @waltinator No I was just wondering about software programs not interested in making any hardware changes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other older tools, like `laptop-mode-tools` and `pm-utils`. However, TLP is the best, most up to date, and does the most.

You can install it by running:

```
sudo apt install tlp tlp-rdw
```

and run it by

```
sudo tlp bat
```

To install pm-utils

```
sudo apt install pm-utils
```

and run it by

```
sudo pm-powersave true
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific, advantages of one or the other.

Comment: I already have tlp, I was looking for something more advance. Please re-read the question because I stated this already.

Comment: You're two usernames have a great coincidence I must say! :D

Comment: Mine was first, NerdOfCode copied me.

Comment: Thats what he/she says about everything.